# Нужно отнять число от переменной

Tags: php, html, html5

Возникла проблема. В данный момент переменная $numExp равна 47128. При вычитании прогресс бар просто пропадает. Помогите, пожалуйста

```
echo '<progress value="'.$numExp - 50000.'" max="50000"></progress>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно пропадает. Прогресс может быть от 0% до 100% (минимум **всегда 0**), а при "47128 - 50000" будет отрицательное значение. Вы видели прогресс бар с -14% например?